Lemma 4.3.1 in Finite von Neumann Algebras and Masas
Let $B$ be a von Neumann subalgebra of a finite von Neumann algebra $N$. Let $A=B\otimes\mathbb{C}I$ and $M=N\otimes M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. In the proof of part (ii) of the Lemma below, I am trying to understand why $(I-P)Y=Y$. Is this because $\mathbb{E}_{A}(YY^{*})$ and $Y$ have the same range projection? I don't see why that would be, but I also don't have a good understanding of what $\mathbb{E}_{A}$ is. Is it even true that $L^{2}(M)=\bigoplus_{n}L^{2}(N)$?
Edit: I believe $L^{2}(M)$ is actually $L^{2}(N)\bigotimes M_{n}$, so I am confused how to interpret such expressions as $Xe_{A}\mathbb{E}_{A}(YY^{*})e_{a}X^{*}$ which seems to be acting on $\bigoplus_{n} L^{2}(N)$. It seems that $e_{A}$ should be something like the $n\times n$ matrix with $e_{B}$ on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere but I am not sure how to justify this given that $e_{A}=e_{B}\otimes e_{\mathbb{C} I}$ acts on $L^{2}(N)\bigotimes M_{n}$ in a way that seems complicated to me because I don't know how $e_{\mathbb{C} I}$ works.



The following is a general fact:
Proposition: Let $A \subset M$ be a von Neumann subalgebra of a tracial von Neumann algebra $M$. Let $Y \in M$ and $P$ a projection in $A$ s.t. $P\mathbb{E}_A(YY^\ast) = 0$. Then $PY = 0$.
Proof: Indeed, to prove $PY = 0$, as $M$ admits a faithful trace $\tau$, it suffices to show $\tau(PYY^\ast P) = 0$. We have,
$$\tau(PYY^\ast P) = \tau(PYY^\ast) = \tau(P\mathbb{E}_A(YY^\ast)) = 0$$
where the first equality follows from $\tau$ being a trace and $P$ being a projection, while the second inequality follows from $P \in A$. $\square$

Thank you, thank you

Is it true that $L^{2}(M)\cong\bigoplus L^{2}(N)$? It seems to me that $L^{2}(M)$ is actually $L^{2}(N)\otimes M_{n}$ since the tensor product trace on $L^{2}(N)\otimes M_{n}$ is nonzero on all positive matrices.

Please see my edit for a fuller explanation of my question

@SihOASHoihd $L^2(M)$ is $L^2(N) \otimes L^2(M_n)$, that is true. You seem to have confused yourself, thinking that because $X, Y$ are written in matrix form they must act on $\bigoplus L^2(N)$. That is not the case. They are elements of $M$, so they just act by left-multiplication on $L^2(M)$. But I do understand the confusion regarding $e_A$. The author made a mistake. $A$ should not have been defined by $B \otimes \mathbb{C}I$. It should have been $B \otimes M_n$. $e_A$ is only represented by a diagonal matrix with $e_B$ along the diagonal in that case.
